# Sore Muscles from Gymnastics

Tags: muscle-soreness, gymnastics, soreness

Its only been about 2 days since my first gymnastics class and all my muscles are extremely sore. Should I still go today even though I'm still this sore?

Comment: What were the exercises that you performed the first day? Also edit your question to explain about the soreness, if possible. It will help the community understand clearly and give a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The feeling you are experience is [Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness or DOMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_onset_muscle_soreness). It is common for people to experience soreness when they are new to exercise, have restarted after taking a long break, or even are just performing a new movement. It should safe for you to workout again and the soreness will diminish in time.

**However, if your pain prevents you from moving, is accompanied by swelling or inflammation, or causes you concern speak with a medical professional.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go. It's okay to work through soreness. If you're so despairingly sore that you can't lift your arms, don't go to gymnastics, see a doctor.